# Centering Input element and image on the same line using CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to vertically center an input element and small png file on the same line within a div. By centering I mean a single horizontal line would pass through the vertical center of the div, the input element and the png file. The input element is 400px wide by 26px high and png file is 24px wide by 30px high. The container div is 445px wide and 36px high. HTML and CSS are below. The only method I've found to do this so far is to make the input element and png file both position:relative and then use top:, bottom:, left:, or right: offsets to get the positioning exactly where I want them. I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS and using position:relative with specific offsets seems like a brute force method to do this. Is there a simpler, more elegant, or preferred way to do this?

HTML is:

```
<div class="inner">
  <input type="text">
  <img class="mic" src="mic.png">
</div>
```

CSS is:

```css
.inner {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      height: 36px;
      width:445px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      }

input {
      margin-left: auto; 
      margin-right: auto;
      height: 26px;
      width: 400px;
      border: none;
      text-align: left
      }
.mic {
      height: 30px;
      width: 24px;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code sample.
I used verticle-align:middle for image and then used line-height for inner wrapper.

```css
.inner {
     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 445px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 3em; 
      }

input {
        margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 28px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    border:solid 1px #000;    
      }
.mic {
      height: 30px;
      width: 24px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      }
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <input type="text">
  <img class="mic" src="mic.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'flex' css property it's easy to use.

```css
.inner {
    height: 50px;
    width: 445px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding:0 16px;
 
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -ms-flex-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 
 margin:auto;
}
input {
 -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    -ms-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
 
 padding:5px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
 margin-right:8px;
}
.mic {
 height: 30px;
 width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <input type="text">
  <img class="mic" src="mic.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
    .inner {
        height: 36px;
        width: 445px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }

    input {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 26px;
        width: 400px;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .mic {
        height: 30px;
        width: 24px;
    }
    .container{
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:700px;
  
  }
```

```html
<body class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <input type="text">
        <img class="mic" src="http://placehold.it/24x30.png">
    </div>
</body>
```